# Indentation is slow in vimtex

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex, plugin-latex-box

If you try to indent a moderate size `.tex` file (~ 3,000 words/500 lines) using the normal mode command `gg=G`, `vimtex` seems to take some time. However `LaTeX-Box` seems to indent faster. I didn't understand the files in the indent folders of `vimtex` or `LaTeX-Box`, could anyone please elaborate on why there's this delay for `vimtex`?

P.S.- `vimtex`'s indent files have more lines compared to `LaTeX-Box`'s indent files, I am guessing there's more to these files rather than just the difference in the number of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, they are two different implementations, so obviously they will use different amounts of time. vimtex indentation does more, which makes it slower. But I've worked hard on making it fast, and as far as I know, it should not be unreasonable slow for daily use.

Note, indenting a whole ~500 line file with `gg=G` should not be a "daily" activity. Indentation is meant to be "automatic", and the indentation expressions work by assuming that the preceding lines are correctly indented. So, if you use vimtex, then indentation should be acceptably fast. And compared to LaTeX-Box, it should be somewhat more robust and have support for indenting more expressions.